# Spring-Kafka with transactions, multiple threads

Tags: spring-boot, spring-kafka

I got a case where the application consumes messages and produces messages as a response to the consumed messages. This is done using kafka transactions, BUT the app also has a scheduled job that sends Kafka messages at regular intervals (also using transactions since it sends to two topics).

When the scheduled job starts sending, I get this exception:

```
org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: TransactionalId aura-transaction-1: Invalid transition attempted from state IN_TRANSACTION to state IN_TRANSACTION
```

Anyone know what might be the reason?
I'm considering trying with different kafkaTemplates (+ producer factory) to see if that fixes the issue. Since then I can assign a new transaction-id-prefix to the scheduled job. Currently they have the same.

Consumer uses a basic @KafkaListener that is already registered in a transaction from the KafkaMessageListenerContainer. It then produces a message using KafkaTemplate.send(Object).

The scheduled job uses the KafkaTemplate.executeInTransaction functionality and sends to two topics.

Versions: 
Spring Boot 2.1.1
Spring Kafka: 2.2.2

StackTrace:

```
org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: TransactionalId person-identhendelse-lager-1.privat-person-fregIdenthendelse-v1.0: Invalid transition attempted from state IN_TRANSACTION to state IN_TRANSACTION
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.TransactionManager.transitionTo(TransactionManager.java:758)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.TransactionManager.transitionTo(TransactionManager.java:751)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.TransactionManager.beginTransaction(TransactionManager.java:216)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.beginTransaction(KafkaProducer.java:606)
    at org.springframework.kafka.core.DefaultKafkaProducerFactory$CloseSafeProducer.beginTransaction(DefaultKafkaProducerFactory.java:459)
    at org.springframework.kafka.core.KafkaTemplate.executeInTransaction(KafkaTemplate.java:278)
    at no.nav.person.identhendelse.lager.app.aggregat.AggregatIdenthendelsePublisher.sendForPerson(AggregatIdenthendelsePublisher.java:52)
    at no.nav.person.identhendelse.lager.app.aggregat.AggregatScheduledTask.aggregate(AggregatScheduledTask.java:54)
    at no.nav.person.identhendelse.lager.app.aggregat.AggregatScheduledTask$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$7f682c33.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:749)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.proceed(MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.java:88)
    at io.micrometer.core.aop.TimedAspect.timedMethod(TimedAspect.java:77)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor58.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethodWithGivenArgs(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:644)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethod(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:633)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJAroundAdvice.invoke(AspectJAroundAdvice.java:70)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:294)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:98)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:93)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at no.nav.person.utils.precondition.feature.annotation.PreconditionMethodInterceptor.invoke(PreconditionMethodInterceptor.java:22)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:688)
    at no.nav.person.identhendelse.lager.app.aggregat.AggregatScheduledTask$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$e0b597f7.aggregate(<generated>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.ScheduledMethodRunnable.run(ScheduledMethodRunnable.java:84)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:54)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:294)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Added example code:
https://github.com/Lg87/kafka-transaction-example
See readme.md and FIND KafkaException to see the exception that occurs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. When asking questions like this, always provide version information.
2. Show your code and the complete stack trace.
3. You mentioned `transactionTemplate` - don't use a template **as well as** `executeInTransaction` - they are redundant since they both start a transaction.
   We [recently fixed a problem where such "nested" transactions were broken](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/commit/035a3b1f658e6acf2f6c0a7c1d3f5083b0b111a6).

**EDIT**

I found the problem; when using `producerPerConsumerPartition` (default true), producers used by the container should not be added to cache for use by arbitrary `KafkaTemplate` operations.

As a work-around, use a different `DefaultKafkaProducerFactory` for the stand-alone template operations.

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/issues/908

Comment: Thanks for reply, the code is a lot, I can see if I can make simplified version.
Version: Spring boot .2.1.1
Spring-Kafka: 2.2.2

I don't use the transactionTemplate now, but consideres making a new producerfactory/kafkaTemplate for the other thread, so it gets a new transaction-id-prefix

Comment: I edited the question a bit, to include versions and a clarification, also added stackTrace

Comment: I added a github link to an example that reproduces the exception. See bottom of question

Comment: I found the issue; thanks for the sample; see the edit to my answer for a work-around.

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply and work-around. :thumbs-up: